# Change a shapefile from longitude display (-180, 180) to (0, 360) in R

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, shapefile, extent

I am trying to crop a raster file ([ERA dataset](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/CKB/ERA5-Land%3A+data+documentation)) (9x9 km grid on an hourly basis for the entire world) by the extents of the shapefile of Chile.

The raster has a longitude display of (0,360) and the shapefile has a longitude display of (-180,180); this means that the extents don't match and therefore I have to change either one of these files. I tried to use raster::rotate to change the extents of the raster but it is taking a lot of time.

I thought that a faster way would be to instead change the extents of the shapefile. Could you please tell me how I can switch the shapefile extents of the longitudes from (-180,180) to (0,360)?

For reference:

```
extent(ch_shp)
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : -109.455 
#xmax       : -66.41472 
#ymin       : -55.98403 
#ymax       : -17.50755 

extent(ras)
#class      : Extent 
#xmin       : -0.05 
#xmax       : 359.95 
#ymin       : -90.05 
#ymax       : 90.05
```

Thank you!

Comment: `terra::rotate` is really what you want, and write it out to different filename, same extension, then source it with `terra::rast('different_filename'), then crop from that. This 'may' make things go faster.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for getting back to me. terra::rotate was also taking a lot of time, so I went ahead with the solution provided by Robert Hijmans below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With terra, you can adjust the vector data with `shift`, or the more general `rotate`.

```
library(terra)
v <- vect("chile.shp")
s <- shift(v, 360)
```

or

```
r <- rotate(v, left=FALSE)
```

Comment: The first option worked, thank you so much!

Comment: @robert-himans, I quite often feel I am mis-advising, am grateful you solve, but am I sufficiently and consistently off the mark that I should desist?

Comment: @Chris please continue. You contributions are very helpful and often spot on. Nobody is perfect. And this is part of the process.